# Why does Binder not recognize a requirements.txt file?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to load a Jupyter Notebook through mybinder.org.  The repository that the Notebook is in includes a `requirements.txt` file with the content

```
parsl
```

because the Notebook uses the `parsl` library.

When I load the notebook and import the library, execution stops with the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parsl'
```

The `requirements.txt` file is *right there*.  I have no idea what else to do to get mybinder.org to load the module.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the repo you are referring to, one suggestion would be you don't have your `requirements.txt` where it needs to be. If it isn't in the root directory of the repository, it has to be in a folder named `binder`, see [here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-put-my-configuration-files-outside-the-root-of-my-repository).

There is a repo that has `parsl` working. You can fork the repo from [here](https://github.com/Parsl/parsl-tutorial), or alternatively you use https://github.com/Parsl/parsl-tutorial as a basis to make your own and then add in your notebooks.